# Trouble adding and subtracting number from range

Tags: python, sum

my assignment has me take an integer and alternate between addition and subtraction until i reach the number. also i a told to take the positive and negative sum. Any help for i should go about making a range function alternate and how to add/subtract the sums? i believe i would be using the range function but i could be wrong
this is in python(3.3)

Sample run:
Enter N: 4
1 - 2 + 3 - 4 = -2
The positive sum is: 4
The negative sum is: 6

im able to take an input and count up from 1,n but i am unsure as to how i could change signs after every number.
Anything helpful is greatly appreciated!

Comment: SO (StackOverflow) is not a workforce to do your assignment. As a hint: Your question is a basic programming question, so I guess you might be better learning this stuff (Google it): `loop in Python`

Comment: thanks for the input, by no means am i asking for the answer cause that defeats the point. But ill keep reading my book about loops. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use any tricks in looping through your range.  Just maintain a variable that tells you whether you should be adding this time, or subtracting, and alternate that variable with each pass through your loop.

Comment: Thank you. Would i be using a nested loop that separately tracks the last inputed number and add/sub for the total while the original range counts up?

Comment: A single loop is sufficient; nesting should not be necessary.  Just start two running totals before the loop:  initialize postot and negtot to 0.  Set posneg to 1 (for add), and then in your loop, use posneg to tell you what to print, what to add (or subtract).  Then flip posneg from 1 to -1, and you're done with an iteration.  When you exit the loop you'll have printed the output you want and will have the two total values you need.

Comment: thank you so much! this is the exactly what i was needing to understand it!